# Unable to shift into low range when cold on my 100 series Toyota Landcruiser

Tags: toyota, transmission, land-cruiser

It is impossible to shift into lo range when the vehicle is cold. I have changed the oil with no improvement. When the drive is warm there is not a problem.

Comment: Can you add more information?  The 100 series as 4 different inline 6 engines and 2 turbo diesels.  Please provide the year/model and engine.  Can you provide any symptoms?  How do you expect it to work?  Why doesn't it meet expectations?  What is the core issue when cold?  Please describe the core issue in detail.  How is it different when it's hot.  You haven't provided very much data.  Please edit your question and add in as much as you can.  Someone will flow to the issue and give your responses but we have to have data.  Help us be successful.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: Are you trying to get into 4 wheel drive low when you experience the issue?  Do you experience the issue going into 4 wheel drive HI and 2 wheel drive HI when it's cold?  "When the drive is warm there is not a problem"  What do you mean by 'drive'.  The engine?  The driveline?  Please provide detail.  Thanks!

Comment: Any luck?  Can you answer the questions in the comments and add them to your question by editing it?

Comment: DucatiKiller Thank you for your questions. I am new at this so bare with me. The 100 series was manufactured A11/Jun/01 plated in Australia 07/01. We often camp on a river bank which can sometimes require Lo range to get to the top of. When I start the motor and try to select Lo-range this is not possible. The gear leaver will not go into Lo-range it is too stiff to move. I am able to select Hi-range but it is not easy. The gear lever is again very stiff to move. The main gear box changes perfectly. Once you drive about 40-50klm you can select either Hi or Lo-range with ease.